# reading from joined query in flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

After successfully joining two db tables, I'm trying to read the data from the 2nd table by addressing the first. I'm addressing `opinion.topic_name` from my jinja2 template, but nothing is returned.
How can I access the Topic.topic_name value from the joined query?

#### view

```
@main.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = IndexForm()
    opinions = []
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        opinions = Opinion.query
                    .filter_by(party_id=form.party.data)
                    .filter_by(topic_id=form.topic.data)
                    .join('topic')
                    .all()
    return render_template('index.html', form=form, opinions=opinions)
```

#### model

```
class Opinion(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = db.Column(db.String(2000))
    topic_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('topic.id'))
    party_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('party.id'))

class Topic(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    topic_name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    opinions = db.relationship(Opinion, backref='topic')
```

#### template (jinja2)

```
<div>
    {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
</div>
<div>
    {% for opinion in opinions %}
    <div class='jumbotron'>
        <h1>{{ opinion.topic_name }}</h1>
        <p>{{ opinion.text }}</p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Probably, you should be calling `opinion.topic.topic_name` instead of `opinion.topic_name` in your template

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This query:

```
opinions = Opinion.query
                    .filter_by(party_id=form.party.data)
                    .filter_by(topic_id=form.topic.data)
                    .join(Topic)
                    .all()
```

will return a list of Opinion models and since in your relationship in `Topic` model, you defined it as:

`opinions = db.relationship(Opinion, backref='topic')`

Then, in your jinja2 template, to access `Topic.topic_name`, you should do:

`<h1>{{ opinion.topic.topic_name }}</h1>`

Comment: In the order you're proposing, the query returns the error `sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Entity '<class 'app.models.Topic'>' has no property 'party_id'`. I tried your order before and didn't understand why it would not work. The solution in the jinja2 template solved the problem though!

Comment: I think with my order, the `filter_by` args will be referring to `Topic` table instead of `Opinion` table, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @JoostBarendregt, if you have other concerns about this answer, add them in comments, otherwise, if it did solve your issue then please, do accept it and may be thumb's up :)