# Reading through joined query Sqlalchemy Jinja

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, jinja2

I am trying to display a doctors first name from another table that is linked by foreign key.  I can get the doctor_id to display but cannot get his name to display.

I looked at this solution 
[reading from joined query in flask-sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41649124/reading-from-joined-query-in-flask-sqlalchemy) 
but it is slightly different as I am querying from the other side and cannot use the backref value as a reference.  I have removed the irrelevant code.

```
 class Appointment(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    patient_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('patient.id'), 
    nullable=False)
    doctor_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('doctor.id'), 
    nullable=False)

class Doctor(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(30), unique=False, nullable=False)
    appointments = db.relationship('Appointment', backref = 
    db.backref('doctor',lazy=True))
```

and the query

```
all_appmts = db.session.query(Appointment)
.filter_by(patient_id=id)
.join(Doctor)

result =appointments_schema.dump(all_appmts)
return render_template('patient.html', all_appointments=result.data)
```

and this is what i tried

```
 {% for a in all_appointments %}
 <td>{{ a.doctor_id.first_name }}</td>
 {% endfor %}
```

The doctor name displayed should be based on the the doctor id for that appointment.

Here is the marshmallow part.

```
class AppointmentSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        # Fields to expose
        fields = ('id','start_datetime', 'end_datetime', 'title', 
        'patient_id', 'doctor_id')

appointments_schema = AppointmentSchema(many=True)
```

Comment: if you can able to print result.data, what does it display ?

Comment: I am able to print result.data but I can only print the data from that table.  Trying to print `a.doctor_id.first_name`  prints nothing.

Comment: As per reference question you mentioned, did you try using like this, appointments = db.relationship(Appointment, backref ='doctor') in Doctor Object.

Comment: I get this error `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'dict object' has no attribute 'doctor'` when my html is `{{ a.doctor.first_name }}` and my query is `all_appmts =db.session.query(Appointment).filter_by(patient_id=id).join(Doctor).all()`

Comment: define \_\_tablename\_\_ = 'doctor' for Doctor class, same way for appointment class also.

Comment: same error without changing the html

Comment: I am quite convinced that the error is not with the SQLAlchemy part, but with what happens to the result in `appointments_schema.dump()`. What exactly is `appointment_schema`? What does `result` contain after calling `dump` on `appointment_schema`?

Comment: `appointment_schema` is the marshmallow part. I have included that in my question now.  `result` contains the json of all of the appointments and I am confident this is not the issue as I am able to display the appointment information in html.  I believe the issue is how I am trying to access the name of the doctor through the query and there is some syntax error in my query.

Comment: Well, have you tried validating your claim? It seems that you only expose the direct attributes of the `Appointment` objects in your schema, not the relationship `doctor`. What does `print([r.doctor.first_name for r in all_appmts.all()])` right after your query do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access `doctor_id.first_name`. But the name of the relationship is `doctor`. If you are converting the result of the query to a list of dicts, then you should serialize the `appointment.doctor` relationship also, so that the dict looks like

```
{
 id: 12,
 doctor: {
  id: 34
 }
}
```

Then you can access it like this

```
 <td>{{ a.doctor.first_name }}</td>
```

But if you are just planning to use it in jinja template, then what is the need to serialize the objects? Instead you can just pass the result of the `query.all()` to the template. Jinja can directly access the python objects and show the data. So instead of `result =appointments_schema.dump(all_appmts)`, try doing this

```
all_appmts = db.session.query(Appointment)
.filter_by(patient_id=id)
.join(Doctor)
return render_template('patient.html', all_appointments=all_aptmts.all())
```

And then keep the jinja template as the same

```
 {% for a in all_appointments %}
 <td>{{ a.doctor.first_name }}</td>
 {% endfor %}
```

It will work

Comment: In the last code block you still have the incorrect `a.doctor_id.first_name` from the OP's example ;)

Comment: excellent thankyou! It works. You've also helped me understand marshmallow better I realise now why it wasn't working.